# Why does series-NMOS gate drive current affect the load, and how do I avoid it?

Tags: mosfet, current, switching, parasitic-capacitance

**TL;DR: With two nMOSFETs in series, why does the load experience current spikes during switching times of one transistor even when the other is off - and how can I avoid it?**

Consider the following circuit, simulated in LTspice:

[image: IR emitter driver circuit]

Use case: It's a boiled-down version of an IR emitter driver I'm trying to design, which modulates a lower-frequency pulse train `B` on top of a higher-frequency carrier signal `A`, as in the [Philips RC-6 remote control protocol](https://www.sbprojects.net/knowledge/ir/rc6.php). For the purposes of this question, unimportant details like the LED itself, gate pull-downs, etc. have been removed.

When I simulate the circuit and check the load current across R3, I see this:

[image: LTspice simulation]

When Q1 is off, the load still sees some current spikes (upper yellow circle) when Q2 switches - up to 3 mA, which is plenty to get some unintended light out of an LED. I understand that due to gate capacitance, there can be high current when switching the transistor (lower yellow circle). And I know I can limit this current by increasing the value of R1 and R2.

But what I don't understand is why these current spikes are transferred (directly or indirectly) to the load. **Why is this?**

If I increase R1 and R2 to 10k, both the gate drive current and the spikes seen by the load are drastically reduced:

[image: LTspice simulation 2]

But consequently the switching is much slower, and the edges aren't as crisp. R3 also still sees current spikes up to 160 uA - much better, but not perfect.

**Is there another way to modify the circuit**, without limiting gate current, so that the load does not see current spikes during switching times of one transistor when the other is off?

*To clarify: For this particular application, I'm sure increasing R1 and R2 is a workable solution, and at these frequencies, BJTs might be a better choice anyway. But this is a learning experience for me, and I'd like to understand this behavior. **Thanks in advance!***

Comment: There's also capacitance from drain to source, Coss.

Comment: @JohnD Ok, so it's not related to the gate capacitance - and the fact that limiting gate current also reduces the load spikes is actually because the transistor switches slower and distributes the Coss charge/discharge over a longer time? I think that makes sense. Could I eliminate the load spikes altogether, and how? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @JohnD: Coss=CDS+CDG. It includes the Miller capacitance.

Comment: You say you have stripped down the circuit for exposition purposes. Are the oscillograms you show from the stripped down version, or the full circuit? I ask because when I simulate this circuit in CircuitLab (using 2N7000s) I get 0.3 mA spikes, not 3 mA. Just trying to track down this discrepancy.

Comment: @RussellH Right- though if a FET stays off, there’s no negative voltage gain and therefore no Miller effect on CDG.  The capacitance is still somewhat non-linear with voltage though.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy All plots are from the stripped-down version shown here.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you have implemented, (if one takes as output, the voltage at the drain of what you label as Q1) is a NAND gate. If both inputs are high, the output is low. Otherwise, the output is high.

Similarly, the steady state output when the gate of Q1 is low and the gate of Q1 is high, is a high output.

But when you change *both* inputs in opposite directions at the same time, or near the same time, you get a glitch. The output goes low, or attempts to go low, and the current through R3 goes up, or attempts to go up.

In the state just prior to the appearance of (the larger) current glitches shown circle in the images below, the gate of Q1 is high and the gate of Q2 is low. At the moment of the glitch, the gate of Q1 switches to low, and the gate of Q2 switches to high.

[image]
The steady state output when the gate of Q1 is high and the gate of Q1 low, is a high output (very little current through R3).

Changing both inputs to a NAND gate in opposite directions at the same time, or near the same time, creates what is known as a logic hazard. The only safe solution to avoid the glitch is to not switch the inputs in opposite directions at the same time, or near the same time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF1rcd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I implemented the above schematic and set the phase offset of the 5 kHz signal to 2 degrees. This made the glitch much worse.

[image]
[image]

There are some much smaller current spikes that are caused by some of the gate current being diverted via the gate-drain capacitance into the drain. In the CircuitLab simulation, these are very much smaller current spikes, well under 10 uA, and not really visible in the images I have posted, but visible in blown up images.

FYI, I am not getting the same current values as you in simulation, so I wonder if there is some difference between our circuits, or between our circuits, and the circuit you used to get your results. However, it doesn't really matter for my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the spikes I'm interested in occur when Q2 switches while Q1 is steady-off. So I don't think simultaneous input transitions can be a factor here, and indeed I see exactly the same effect if I shift `B` 90° out of phase.

Comment: @TypeIA I have added an image of V2 and V3 to match up with I_R3. You can see that in fact the glitch occurs when V2 and V3 change in opposite directions more or less simultaneously.

Comment: That's true for one event, but I still see spikes (of lesser magnitude than the first) at subsequent transitions of `B` while `A` is zero. So perhaps there are two independent effects at work here. I guess I should learn about both. I'm familiar with logic glitches (I do a lot of digital and FPGA design) but in this circuit, can you explain the mechanism _why_ it occurs? I suspect the commenters talking about parasitic drain/source capacitance are on the right track here. I'm hoping for an answer that explains the mechanism and that also explains the subsequent spikes. Thanks again.

Comment: @TypeIA it is true for the spikes you circled. The smaller spikes are due to gate current capacitively coupled to the drain.